# How connect DirectToolItem wiht the Part in e4

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have added a toolbar in a Part that contain a DirectToolItem.

So in my files i have a class for the part and a class for DirectToolItem

[code from the Part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01Qhd.png)

[code from the toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXmcb.png)

How i connect this 2 class, i want call from @Execute of DirectToolItem a method inside the class of the Part

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the currently active `MPart` in your execute method using the `IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_PART` name. The `getObject()` method of `MPart` returns your part class:

```java
@Execute
public void execute(@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_PART) MPart mpart)
{
  PartStackOverflow part = (PartStackOverflow)mpart.getObject();

  ... call methods
}
```

Alternatively use the `find` method of `EModelService` to find your part by its id.